# How do i implement my own hooks in elisp?

Tags: hooks

What code do i need to implement in order to create a hook which can be set by the user and which is called in my own function?

Comment: You might want to provide an example where you'd want to do that, to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE (emacs)!  Look up `run-hooks` which gives the whole story but the tl;dr is expose a hook variable `my-fancy-hook` to the user and at the right place in yr own code put:

```
(run-hooks 'my-fancy-hook)
```